# AutoLayout, constraints , iPhone 3.5 inch and 4 inch

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.5

We are having a problem in the new Auto Layout system
How can we make a fully customised view works on both screens ?
with no white or empty space

Note:If there is a video please provide it and please tell us your Impression and experiences

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Th best video I can recommend is the WWDC videos.

There are several WWDC 2012 videos about AutoLayout.